# Hide emacs icon when client is off

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon

I am running emacs as daemon, in MacOSX, it works flawlessly but when I kill the client the icon remains in the dock as running. I searched around for a way to hide it when no client is running but I couldn't find any workaround. Has anyone found a way to do this.